IC recessed lighting with no insulation
A few years ago, I replaced my non-ic lights that used 75 watt halogen bulbs with IC rated lights with LED bulbs. The space above has no insulation and I did not add any. I did it basically as to save electricity as the LEDs use very little electricity. The LEDs are good for up to 15 years.
I just got to thinking. Do IC lights need to have insulation around them? Are they okay in a non-insulated space? I'm just wondering because my attic is very tight and has to be crawled through, not the easiest thing to do.

The basic problem is that lights generate heat. How much heat does vary based on the lighting technology - incandescent/halogen produces a lot more heat for a given amount of light than an LED light. Broadly speaking you can just look at power in (Watts) = heat out. It isn't quite that bad, especially with LEDs, but close enough.
With a light that is hanging from the ceiling then the heat dissipates very easily, though even then there is a limit. I often find paint damaged above light fixtures because of the cumulative effect of years of heat from incandescent bulbs. But inside a ceiling it becomes a much bigger concern, and if the area above the fixture inside the ceiling is insulated - which is common if the space above the ceiling is an attic/roof - then it is an even bigger problem because insulation, by definition, prevents heat from escaping.
This means that:

You should always be careful to not exceed the manufacturer's limits on light size based on power. This is especially a problem with traditional screw-in bulbs because a lamp rated for 40W can easily take a 100W bulb and produce so much heat that it can burn up the fixture itself or the lamp shade or whatever is around it.

A recessed fixture rated for non-IC contact should not be used with insulation because you run the risk of producing more heat than can be safely dissipated.

A recessed fixture rated for IC contact is perfectly fine when used without insulation. But even in that case, stick to the rated power limit.



Glad to know my IC lights are okay without insulation! Thanks!
